# error when injecting service in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to consume Web API using AngularJs but getting struck angular side which is hard for me to figure out.

I created HTML, controller and service. Everything seems ok to me but when running the app i get the injection error.

```
html
<html >
<head>
    <title>Motors </title>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="/View/motorController.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="motorController">
    <div>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Country</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="m in motors">
                <td>{{m.Id}}</td>
                <td>{{m.Name}}</td>
                <td>{{m.Country}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**AngularJs controller**

```
var module = angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('motorController', ['$scope', '$motorService',function ($scope, motorService) {

    getMotors();
    function getMotors() {
        motorService.GetAllMotors()
            .success(function (motors) {
                $scope.motors = motors;
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                $scope.status = 'Unable to load motor data: ' + error.message;
            });
    }
}]);
```

**angular service**

```
motorApp.factory('motorService', function ($http) {
    var urlBase = 'http://localhost:40738/api';
    var motorService = {};

    motorService.GetAllMotors = function () {
        return $http.get(urlBase + '/GetAllMotors');
    };

    return motorService;
});
```

Error i am getting on chrmoe browser console

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $motorServiceProvider <- $motorService <- motorController
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the factory is given a different module name "`motorApp`" instead of module name "`module`".

Use

```
module.factory('motorService', function ($http) { //change here 
    var urlBase = 'http://localhost:40738/api';
    var motorService = {};

    motorService.GetAllMotors = function () {
        return $http.get(urlBase + '/GetAllMotors');
    };

    return motorService;
});
```

Also in your controller you should remove the "$" from injected service name "`motorService`"

```
var module = angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('motorController', ['$scope', 'motorService',function ($scope, motorService) {

    getMotors();
    function getMotors() {
        motorService.GetAllMotors()
            .success(function (motors) {
                $scope.motors = motors;
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                $scope.status = 'Unable to load motor data: ' + error.message;
            });
    }
}]);
```

Comment: i tried again with the changes you suggested above but unfortunately it did not work out. I am still getting the same error. Probably, worth to mention that i am trying it in visual studio and not in notepad.

Comment: I would suggest to please create a plunker for the same

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/znQAALOhbb9Pb279E4Gy?p=preview   in this plnkr i put service and controller in same file but in reality they will be in different files. I am even fine if you check this plnkr and track the issue. thanks

Comment: Here, in this plunker the problem is that there are 2 ng-apps defined , one on the html tag and other on the body . If you remove the one on the html , everything will work fine. Please clarify.

Comment: Also if you are loading service and controller in different files , how are you refering to the module in the file where the module is not defined??

Comment: If you are loading service and controller in different files for the same module, you should be careful that you are loading the file in which you have defined the module first and loading other files after wards. Please refer to the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cN71NTInkygSXpKAhKRO?p=preview) fore reference

Comment: Excellent, the problem was as you highlighted "you are loading the file in which you have defined the module first and loading other files after wards"

Answer (score 3):

You have a extra $ infront of MotorService, change

**From:**

```
 .controller('motorController', ['$scope', '$motorService',function ($scope, motorService)
```

**To:**

```
 .controller('motorController', ['$scope', 'motorService',function ($scope, motorService)
```

Comment: I removed extra $ infront of MotorService but still the result same. Same error i am getting.

Comment: Yes, i did . This is complete error "Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: motorServiceProvider <- motorService <- motorController
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/unpr?p0=motorServiceProvider%20%3C-%20motorService%20%3C-%20motorController"

Comment: may be you have given a different app name in the js file as sahil mentioned above